# How to plot data on time differences?

Tags: angular, angular6, amcharts

I have multiple data on each date for example i have 6 data values those need to plot single date. How would i plot them?

I am passing millisecond values in date in ForLoop under  ***generateChartData() function***:

```
let newDate = new Date(parseInt(this.vitalHistoryEachData[i]['observation-time'])); //1504549740000,1504535400000,1504532700000,1504530900000

newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
// output Mon Sep 04 2017 23:59:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Mon Sep 04 2017 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Mon Sep 04 2017 19:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Mon Sep 04 2017 18:45:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 

chartData.push({
date: newDate,
DataSet1: DataSet1,
DataSet2: DataSet2
});
```

I have setup date format also:

```
// Set date label formatting
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

But my values are not plotting as expected.
[image]

> It should be view like below:

[image]

Comment: Could it be that since you have your data as HH:mm:ss but your .setKey is (.., ...HH:mm" it might not be able to read your data correctly? Could you try set your key to HH:mm:ss, or share a stackblitz example?

Comment: Already tried. It is not working with HH:mm or HH:mm:ss also. Actually it is not able to pick time due to same it is plotting same date data on single segment only.

Comment: Could the current amcharts implementation that you use, be the same as this https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/ ?

Comment: Yes but I am using typescript code not JS

Comment: Hmmm. I find it difficult since there is little given code. But maybe consider looking at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/ since the way to set the axes seems different than the way you do.

Comment: Can you provide your complete config please? I created a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzzxzK) with your dates and it worked out of the box, so I think the error might be somewhere else.

Comment: Hi..!!! Thankyou Everyone for your help but @amcharts team has resolved my issue. there was some issues and need to customize code config. They provided me wonderful support and resolved my issue. If anyone wants then they can track all details at https://amcharts.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/42142